# ggplot by group with filter()

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

I have big dataset with the following format:

```
   structure(list(LOCATION = c("CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", 
"CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN"), Country = c("Canada", "Canada", 
"Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", 
"Canada"), SUBJECT = c("ULABUL99", "ULABUL99", "ULABUL99", "ULABUL99", 
"ULABUL99", "ULABUL99", "ULABUL99", "ULABUL99", "ULABUL99", "ULABUL99"
), Subject = c("Unit Labour Cost", "Unit Labour Cost", "Unit Labour Cost", 
"Unit Labour Cost", "Unit Labour Cost", "Unit Labour Cost", "Unit Labour Cost", 
"Unit Labour Cost", "Unit Labour Cost", "Unit Labour Cost"), 
    SECTOR = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Sector = c("Total Economy", 
    "Total Economy", "Total Economy", "Total Economy", "Total Economy", 
    "Total Economy", "Total Economy", "Total Economy", "Total Economy", 
    "Total Economy"), MEASURE = c("ST", "ST", "ST", "ST", "ST", 
    "ST", "ST", "ST", "ST", "ST"), Measure = c("Level, ratio or national currency", 
    "Level, ratio or national currency", "Level, ratio or national currency", 
    "Level, ratio or national currency", "Level, ratio or national currency", 
    "Level, ratio or national currency", "Level, ratio or national currency", 
    "Level, ratio or national currency", "Level, ratio or national currency", 
    "Level, ratio or national currency"), FREQUENCY = c("A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), Frequency = c("Annual", 
    "Annual", "Annual", "Annual", "Annual", "Annual", "Annual", 
    "Annual", "Annual", "Annual"), TIME = 1970:1979, Time = 1970:1979, 
    Value = c(0.1304592, 0.1357066, 0.1430287, 0.1521136, 0.1752398, 
    0.2018611, 0.2193767, 0.2347496, 0.2470616, 0.2663881), Flag.Codes = c("E", 
    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E"), Flags = c("Estimated value", 
    "Estimated value", "Estimated value", "Estimated value", 
    "Estimated value", "Estimated value", "Estimated value", 
    "Estimated value", "Estimated value", "Estimated value")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

And I want to draw time plot like the following (for each sector group in a particular country's particular subject, in this case, Germany's Labour Income Share)
[image]

I tried to code as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df <- read.csv("/Users/ulc.csv", header = TRUE)
fsector = factor(df$SECTOR)
df %>%
  filter(df$MEASURE =="ST",
df$SUBJECT == "ULAIRU99",
         df$LOCATION == "DEU") %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = df$year, y = df$value, color =  fsector, linetype = fsector)) +
scale_color_manual(labels=c("Sec 1","Sec 2", "Sec 3", "Sec 4", "Sec 5", "Sec 6", "Sec 7", "Sec 8"), values = 1:8) + 
scale_linetype_manual(labels=c("Sec 1","Sec 2", "Sec 3", "Sec 4", "Sec 5", "Sec 6", "Sec 7", "Sec 8"), values = 1:8) + 
theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.3), legend.title = element_blank()) +
ylab("LIS of Germany by sector") + xlab("year")
```

But the result does not show any plots and seems like a lot of elements are missing in my code. Maybe should I add geom_line() for each sector? But there seems much simpler way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should be `filter(SUBJECT == "ULABULAA"...` and `aes(x = year, y = value,...`

Comment: Should also define `fsector` within the dataframe so it's not a free-floating vector which probably won't be aligned to `df`, especially after filtering. e.g. `df$fsector = factor(df$sector)` and then your other code.

Comment: @JonSpring, thanks after editing I got `object 'year' not found` msg. Is it because now I have filtered df different from initial `df`?

Comment: No, it means you probably have a column name which is different than what you are showing. `filter` doesn't change the columns. Please provide subset of your data using `dput(head(df, 10))`

Comment: @RonakShah, I edited my data according to your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code -

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  filter(MEASURE =="ST",SUBJECT == "ULAIRU99",LOCATION == "DEU") %>%
  mutate(SECTOR = factor(SECTOR)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = TIME, y = Value, color =  SECTOR, linetype = SECTOR)) +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_color_manual(labels=c("Sec 1","Sec 2", "Sec 3", "Sec 4", "Sec 5", "Sec 6", "Sec 7", "Sec 8"), values = 1:8) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(labels=c("Sec 1","Sec 2", "Sec 3", "Sec 4", "Sec 5", "Sec 6", "Sec 7", "Sec 8"), values = 1:8) + 
  theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.3), legend.title = element_blank()) +
  ylab("LIS of Germany by sector") + xlab("year")
```

Comment: Still I cannot see any plots. Does it mean that I should specify `geom_line()` or do I miss anything here?

Comment: Yes, you were missing `gom_line` and also you had incorrect column names. Do you really have that combination of data that you are filtering for? If I use the combination that you have provided the data for it works with this - `...filter(MEASURE =="ST",SUBJECT == "ULABUL99",LOCATION == "CAN") %>%...` Does `df %>%
  filter(MEASURE =="ST",SUBJECT == "ULAIRU99",LOCATION == "DEU")` returns more than 0 rows?

Comment: You are right. I just fixed incorrect column names. Then it works fine. Thanks a bunch!